# MongoDB db.runCommand() from C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, sharding

Hi I'm using C# with MongoDB Official driver v2.2.4 and I want to run db.runCommand() on the admin database.

So far i have this and i am able to connect to the admin database but db.runCommand is giving me this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in MongoDB.Bson.dll Additional information: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'."

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
database = client.GetDatabase("admin");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");
var commandResult = database.RunCommand<string>(@"db.createCollection(test1)");
```

After I resolve this test I want to run this command from C# but I am stuck.

```
db.runCommand( { addshard : “localhost:10001”, name : “shard10001” } );
```

Any one can resolve this problem and provide me with a good explanation and example. After some search I have tried this code does seems to make more sense but still getting an error.
 "`Additional information: Command addshard failed: no such command: 'addshard', bad cmd: '{ addshard: "192.168.1.4:27017", name: "shard1" }'."`

Any ideas please of what I'm doing wrong! Thanks.

```
    var addShardCommand = new BsonDocument {
        { "addshard", "192.168.1.4:27017"},
        { "name", "shard1" }
    };
    var addShardResult = database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(addShardCommand);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what is the correct command in mongodb. like sometime name need Document object instead of just string.

I am using something like this. check if this help

```
var name = new BsonDocument { { "name", "regions" } };
var command = new BsonDocument { { "listCollections", 1 }, { "filter", name } };
var result = Database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
var k = result.ToJson();
```

Here name is again object which I found from this documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/

Some more help you can take from here
https://zetcode.com/csharp/mongodb/