# How to call a stored JavaScript in MongoDb from C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm evaluating the porting of SQL Server database to MongoDb.

The problem is moving stored procedures, I read about MongoDb stored JavaScript and I would like make some test in in .Net. I've installed MongoDb driver 2.4.0 and created this function on MongoDb named `test_function`:

```
function (x) 
{
  return x;
}
```

This is the code I use to try to invoke that function:

```
MongoClient oMongoClient = new MongoClient(Properties.Settings.Default.MongoCN);
IMongoDatabase oMongoDatabase = oMongoClient.GetDatabase("test_db");
var result = oMongoDatabase.RunCommand<BsonDocument>("test_function(3)");
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in MongoDB.Bson.dll
>   Additional information: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'test_function'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this way to run a stored script:

```
var cmd = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{ eval: \"test_function(2)\" }");
var result = db.RunCommand(cmd);
```

But result is in `BsonDocument` to get the correct result you can use this methods:

```
var intResult = result["retval"].ToInt32();
```

Comment: when the function return a number it works fine. Now i  want to try to return a document's list. i changed test_function to this: function (x,y) 
{
    return db.MyDB.find({_id:1});
} running into mongo shell it return one document. but from dotnet it does not work.

Comment: @FDB AFAIK you can't get results of database commands in this way in C#, please ask another question for that and I hope someone answers it ;).

Answer (score 3):

The exact same question was here: [MongoDB db.runCommand() from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645151/mongodb-db-runcommand-from-c-sharp)

My first answer was there, but I think, it's better to do here.

I think you could call with this code:

```
var doc = new BsonDocument(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "test_function", "3" }});
var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<int>(doc);
var result = db.RunCommand(command );
```

But, as you could see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719660/call-mongodb-stored-javascript-function-in-c-sharp-net), it is really not recommended to use stored procedures this way.

I have found another solution here:

https://gist.github.com/jamesikanos/b5897b1693b5c3dd1f87

With this snippet, you could call your function this way:

```
db.EvalAsync("test_function(2)").Result
```

Comment: thanks, it still throws exception: An unhandled exception of type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll

Additional information: Command test_function failed: no such cmd: test_function.

Comment: got the same exception. Sorry, i have found another way of doing it, see update of the answer.

Comment: eval and EvalAsync has been removed in 2.4.0 driver. I Think it is impossible to call a stored js from the client. Also there's no way to migrate sql server storted procedures to Mongo. My evaluation is ended, i realized it is impossible.