# How can I run my MongoDB function in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a complicated aggregate function which I think it is better to run on the MongoDB server and its name is "myFunc".  How can I run that from c# code to get best performance?
Is it better to use it as MongoDB function or write it by using .net driver and run it on C# code?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015598/how-to-call-a-stored-javascript-in-mongodb-from-c-sharp

Comment: I saw that before. But I have read some documents that recommend that do not use `eval` command because it has very low performance. I want to now Which one is better call function in this way or use .Net Driver